# Condition in WHERE statement in HiveSQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

This might be trivial, but I have a simple query with conditions in the WHERE statement. The issue is that I would like one condition to exist if another is true based on a Hive variable declared outside of the query.

```
SELECT something
FROM some_table
WHERE condition1 and condition2 and "if condition3 happens, then condition4".
```

For example:

If condition3 is something like: ${hiveconf:variable}<5: then include condition4, which would be "and attribute is not null". This hive variable is used in different queries and is defined at the beginning of the code. The idea is that depending on what this variable is, include this fourth condition into my query.

Hope this is somewhat clear, but sorry for the poor explanation.

This would be an IF THEN DO statement in SAS, if that helps.

Comment: I presume you can use `CASE WHEN .. THEN .. ELSE ... END` clause(even though I don't know hive)

Comment: To be completely honest, I'm not sure how a case when statement works in the where clause.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[SQL Conditional Where](//stackoverflow.com/q/353425/90527)", "[IF Inside WHERE with stored procedure](//stackoverflow.com/q/14967397/90527)"

Comment: Note that the use of a HiveQL variable has no impact on the issue of conditional expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case-when` in select clause and case when in where clause ar pretty much same/similar. You just need to assign a value based on conditions and the equate it with same value.

```
SELECT something
FROM some_table
WHERE 
condition1 and condition2 and 
CASE WHEN condition3 AND condition4 then 1 else 0 END = 1 -- this case when will ensure condition3 and 4 must be true so this whole case when will be true.
```

For your example, you can use something like this -

```
CASE WHEN  ${hiveconf:variable}<5 AND and attribute is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END =1
```

You can write different case when or nested case when as per your requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I've been after

Comment: youre welcome, hope it helped you... pls mark it as answer if it worked :)

Comment: Thanks for this response, this has helped me out today. However I think to nullify condition4 the CASE statement should always evaluate to TRUE, so the WHERE statement only depends on condition1 and condition2.  To do this I think the answer should be changed in a couple of ways
- condition 3 should be a NOT i.e. ${hiveconf:variable} >= 5
- the AND within the CASE statement should be an OR
This ensures that when condition 3 is False the CASE statement always evaluates to True, nullifying condition4.